# How to create a sharable class so other can use for their websites

Tags: html, class, icons, share

Does anyone knows a tutorial on how to create a sharable class [like this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)? 
For example when you add

i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"

on your webpage and you have the required link rel tags an icon will appear in your website

Comment: you mean create a stylesheet.css file with classes to be used by several  pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah sure you can do that!

Just create a CSS file which gives styles of various class and id. 
If someone use this css file and have required classes in the code, they will get the style.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can choose this as a best answer then! :)